# pandas - Count use of value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the amount of times a distinct user has used a value. Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd
user = ['1', '2', '3', '1']
val = [['a','b','c'],['a'],['c','d'],['a','d']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': user, 'val': val})

user    val
 1      [a, b, c]
 2      [a]
 3      [c, d]
 1      [a, d]
```

and my expected output is as below:

```
val     count
 a      2
 b      1
 c      2
 d      2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need flattening lists per group first, get unique values by `set` and flattening again with count by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) or `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

s = df.groupby('user')['val'].apply(lambda x: set([item for sub in x for item in sub]))

df = (pd.Series([item for sublist in s for item in sublist])
        .value_counts()
        .sort_index()
        .rename_axis('val')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Or:

```
df = (pd.Series(Counter([item for sublist in s for item in sublist]))
       .sort_index()
       .rename_axis('val')
       .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
  val  count
0   a      2
1   b      1
2   c      2
3   d      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
user = ['1', '2', '3', '1']
val = [['a','b','c'],['a'],['c','d'],['a','d']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': user, 'val': val})

pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.groupby("user").val.apply(lambda s:set(chain.from_iterable(s))))))
```